# Confused about right naming convention

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Some time ago I read following rules:

- local variables, parameters are written with Camel case
- field, properties, methods with Pascal

However then I have seen that in using properties, the property should be Pascal and that private field camel. So I am confused, what is the correct, standard naming convention?

Comment: You read this _where_? There are many different code style conventions.

Comment: **Public** fields are PascalCased. There is no recommendation for **private** fields. Generally, developers either pascalCase them or _beginThemWithAnUnderscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

> **Do use Pascal casing for all public
>   member, type, and namespace names
>   consisting of multiple words.**
>
> Note that this rule does not apply to
>   instance fields. For reasons that are
>   detailed in the Member Design
>   Guidelines, you should not use public
>   instance fields.
>
> **Do use camel casing for parameter
>   names.**

Since this has been mentioned: A recommendation for underscores as prefix for private fields does not seem to be included in the conventions on MSDN, but the .NET classes are written in that style.

Comment: Err I write it vice versa - property should be Pascal and private field camel, sorry

Comment: That makes more sense indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast naming convention, all kinds of folks go back and forth on private naming, public naming is always Proper (Pascal) case. I prefer _camelCase for private fields as it makes it easier to see that it is just that, but many people choose just this.camelCase instead. With the new .NET syntax if you need only simple properties you can of course avoid that altogether now with the use auf automatic properties:

```
public string MyPublicProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Private fields are usually in camel case with a "_" ( underscore ) prefixed.

Also refer the following for .NET naming conventions:

http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

PS: One thing though, establish a convention for yourself or your team if need be, and STICK to it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that "usually". I never use it, and I'm pretty sure MS doesn't even recommend it.

Comment: Please read the link I have provided. MS does use it as well, thought not recommend it. Actually, MS doesn't care about how private members are named.

Answer (score 0):

The most common convention I have seen is to use **Pascal case** for **Everything** except **variable** where you should use **Camel case** and sometimes prefix them with a underscore (_) if its a private field.

Answer (score 0):

But what to do with a private property..? Resharper doesn't have a sensible solution, personally I use  _PascalCase.

And protected properties?  Same as private properties, I guess.